# Swimming pool skimmer floating weir forces

Tags: fluid-dynamics

How would I calculate the forces required to open the weir gate depending on the depth of the water? The pump is an impeller type, I want full flow to the pump. I assume there are also forces from laminar flow as well as weight of water once the water flows over the weir.

[image: A swimming pool floating weir.]

Comment: So you are assuming the water is basically stationary?

Comment: No it is stationary when the pump is not running on the left of the diagrams. The pump is switched on in the right diagrams and a flow is caused by the vacuum of the pump. I wonder how the forces react when the angle of the lever is altered by the height of the water.